Facebook Developer: Why do the like_count and comments_count of stories always return zero?
Facebook Developer: Why do the like_count and comments_count of stories always return zero?
I called the Facebook API (https://graph.facebook.com/v16.0/17841402939571009/stories?fields=comments_count,id,caption,ig_id,like_count,media_url), but the like_count and comments_count always return zero. What could be the issue?
Please help me. Thanks

what have you tried so far ?
the question needs sufficient code for a minimal reproducible example

Reading from this endpoint returns nodes of the Stories type, and the field list for that does not contain a like_count or a comments_count, see https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/stories/ They do contain a media_id and a post_id, so likely you need to go looking for those counts below one of those.
